# How is the equation for Compliance voltage?

Tags: bjt, compliance

[Here](https://wiki.analog.com/university/courses/electronics/text/chapter-11) is the link for a current mirror discussion. I am trying to understand the meaning of compliance voltage equation and how it can be dervied:
https://wiki.analog.com/university/courses/electronics/text/chapter-11

Attached the same relevant section screen-shot:
[image]

Please advice.

Thanks
VT

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please commit this to memory **forever**. You will need to thoroughly understand it, literally *over and over and over again*.

$$\begin{align*}
\textrm{Shockley equation applied} \\ \textrm{to simplified BJT model}\\ \textrm{ignoring the Early Effect:} \\
I_C&=I_S\cdot\left(e^{\cfrac{V_{BE}}{V_T}}-1\right) \\ \textrm{move }I_S\textrm{ over to the other side,}\\ \cfrac{I_C}{I_S}&=\left(e^{\cfrac{V_{BE}}{V_T}}-1\right) \\ \textrm{Drop the insignificant -1 term,} \\ \cfrac{I_C}{I_S}&\approx e^{\cfrac{V_{BE}}{V_T}} \\\\  \textrm{Take the logarithm of both sides,} \\ \\ \operatorname{ln}\left(\cfrac{I_C}{I_S}\right)&\approx\cfrac{V_{BE}}{V_T} \\ \\ \textrm{Solve for }V_{BE}, \\ \\ V_{BE}&\approx V_T\cdot \operatorname{ln}\left(\cfrac{I_C}{I_S}\right)
\end{align*}$$

You should be able to do the above *in your sleep*. You should understand the meaning of any of the above *in your sleep*.

And you should also know that the *thermal voltage* \$V_T=\frac{n k T}{q}\$ and is approximately \$26\:\textrm{mV}\$ at room temps, that for small signal BJTs \$n\approx 1\$ (but for diodes it is usually larger), and that \$I_S\$ is, itself, *highly* temperature dependent (roughly proportional to the 3rd power of T) and that it dominates the temperature behavior of \$I_C\$ because its effect is not only larger but of opposite sign to the temperature effects caused by \$V_T\$. (The temperature-dependent \$I_S\$ equation is more complicated and not provided here.)

---

Getting back to the point of the current mirror discussion, this just means that you don't want to saturate the BJTs in a mirror -- that's a bad thing as they stop being much of a mirror then. So \$\vert V_{CE}\vert\ge\vert V_{BE}\vert\$, as computed above. Just make sure that the load you attach, together with the mirrored current, doesn't violate that.

Comment: For understanding purpose, How is the scenario if the BJT is in saturation?

Comment: @vt673, A diode-connected BJT can't saturate (Because \$V_{be}=V_{ce}\$).

Comment: @ThePhoton Yeah. But actually that complicates the discussion. There are three regions of behavior and I wanted to AVOID talking about that. In region I, \$I_C\$ is low but still follows a linear line (on a log-lin plot) towards the intercept at \$I_S\$, while \$I_B\$ starts curving towards \$I_S\$, too. (Meaning lower \$\beta\$.) But in region II (normal), there's just a \$\beta\$ factor between them. In region III (crowding), \$I_B\$ continues linearly upwards, while \$I_C\$ curves down (lower \$\beta\$ again.) Do you really think I should explore all that above? I wanted to keep it simple.

Comment: @ThePhoton I mentioned that this was for a "simplified BJT" model and figured that was enough.

Comment: @ThePhoton In Region II (where \$\beta\$ applies well), \$I_C=\beta\cdot I_B\$, which is why \$\beta\$ is actually kind of useful. Ignoring the Early Effect, this doesn't have to be a diode-connected BJT case. More, in the current mirror case this is exactly why the thing works well, at all. (The Early Effect is one of the _problems_ to be dealt with in more complex current mirrors.) I'm not sure I entirely see why the diode-connected bit is needed. But I do see why the Early Effect should be added, so I added that. But maybe my brain is out to lunch today.

Comment: @ThePhoton We may need to take this to chat. There are three models, but I think you are addressing the non-linear hybrid-\$\pi\$. There, \$ \frac{I_{CC}}{\beta_F}  = \frac{I_{S}}{\beta_F} \left(e^{\frac{V}{V_T}}-1\right)\$. \$\beta_F\$ can be cancelled there, easily. And there are not two different \$I_S\$ to worry over. And a Spice model only has one \$\beta_F\$, as well. Maybe I need a kick in the head today.